# SQL NOT IN explanation

Tags: sql

I find my self lost while trying to create an actually pretty easy SQL statement.

I got a database with 3 Tables:

- recipes - storing some recipes names for cooking
- ingredients_recipes - links ingredients with recipes
- ingredients - the ingredients used by recipes.

its stored like this to make it double-clear:

recipes:

```
id | name
 1 | lasagne alla bolognese
 2 | tuna with tomatoes
```

ingredients:

```
id | name
 1 | lasagne slices
 2 | meat
 3 | tomato
 4 | tuna
```

and join-table ingredients_recipes:

```
ingredient_id | recipes_id
            1 | 1
            2 | 1
            3 | 1
            3 | 2
            4 | 2
```

So as you can see, there are 2 really undelicios recipes which I should at least give some spices. But what I want to do before is selecting recipes by ingredients.

I want to have all my recipes having meat **AND** tomatoes:

```
SELECT recipes.name FROM recipes r
INNER JOIN ingredients_recipes ir ON ir.recipes_id = r.id
WHERE ir.ingredient_id IN ( 2 ) AND ir.ingredient_id IN ( 3 )
```

-> lasagna.. fine! (I use IN since there might be a bunch of ingredients, like "tomato", "tomatoes", "tomatoes, sliced" etc.. )

When I want to have e.g. all recipes having tomatoes but NOT having tuna, I tried:

```
SELECT recipes.name FROM recipes r
INNER JOIN ingredients_recipes ir ON ir.recipes_id = r.id
WHERE ir.ingredient_id IN ( 2 ) AND ir.ingredient_id NOT IN ( 4 )
```

-> still getting tuna - since one of the rows i join does not contain ingredient 4. okay :/

What I am wondering now is, what do I have to do, to get my desired results.
I currently put an arrow to my knee by doing a subselect like this:

```
SELECT recipes.name FROM recipes r
INNER JOIN ingredients_recipes ir ON ir.recipes_id = r.id
WHERE (
        ir.ingredient_id IN ( 2 ) -- or more..
        AND 
        recipes.id NOT IN ( SELECT recipes_id FROM ingredients_recipes
                             WHERE ingredient_id IN ( 4 ) -- actually i paste names of the ingredients.. but that is not the case. just to shorten the query.. by filling in a comment twice as long..
                            )
      )
```

as I am quite new to mySQL, I don't even know what to google for. so any help in that case, and o/c the better SQL statement would be ..

```
 IN(awesome).
```

Edit: ah, and yes I actually do grouping.. ;-)

Comment: You need to select the recipes for which **both** an ingredient 2 and 4 are needed.

Comment: A side note - you might want to change table names to a proper spelling of "recipes".

Comment: thanks @too, 100% typo-match in my question ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one way. (untested)

```
SELECT r.name 
FROM recipes r
JOIN ingredients_recipes ir 
  ON ir.recipe_id = r.id
WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT *
    FROM ingredients_recipes ex
    WHERE ex.recipe_id = r.recipe_id
    AND ex.ingredient_id IN ( 2 , 3 )
    GROUP BY nx.recipe_id
    HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
    );
```

The only way for count(*) to be 2 is if 2 and 3 ar both present.

Another way could be: (still untested)

```
SELECT r.name 
FROM recipes r
JOIN ingredients_recipes ir 
  ON ir.recipe_id = r.id
WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT *
    FROM ingredients_recipes ex
    WHERE ex.recipe_id = r.recipe_id
    AND ex.ingredient_id = 2
    )
AND EXISTS ( SELECT *
    FROM ingredients_recipes ex
    WHERE ex.recipe_id = r.recipe_id
    AND ex.ingredient_id = 3
    );
```

UPDATE: (i had misread the question) If you also don't want recipes with particular ingredients *present* you could add yet another subquery "leg" to the query:

```
... AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT *
    FROM ingredients_recipes ex
    WHERE ex.recipe_id = r.recipe_id
    AND ex.ingredient_id IN ( 4,5 )
    );
```

Comment: thanks a lot, wildplaser. question:
query 1 selects all containing ingredient 2 _or_ 3, then you select those having both. query2 those having 2 _and_ 3. issnt the first one a waste of cputime, or, is it even faster than 2nd since the query itself is more simple + comparing numbers (count) only is quite easy done?

Comment: It is a bit more verbose, but clearer for beginners, IMHO. Your "I need at least XXX rows ({x,y,z} to be present" always leads to ugly or big queries. The whole thing is: you can add as many "boolean" conditions as you like to the WHERE clause, without having to change the actual join {recipes,ingrediants} core query. It's just like LEGO ...

Comment: @dhanke, glad you found a working solution! Just FYI, this will execute two subqueries for each recipe. Perhaps it would be better/more efficient to change `EXISTS`/`NOT EXISTS` to `IN`/`NOT IN` so that the subquery is non-correlated.

Comment: @ZaneBien using where x.id IN (wanted) and x.id  NOT IN (not wanted) does not help. guess i got you wrong?

Comment: WRT the number of subqueries: Will depend on the DBMS, obviously. The postgres optimiser might be able to merge them into one (but I am not sure). Premature optimisation is the root of all evil, anyway ...

Comment: @wildplasser yes, i dont want to optimize anything yet - i am happy its working;)

Answer (score 2):

Try this flexible solution:

*This query will retrieve recipes which contain both ingredients `1` and `2`, and do not contain ingredients `4` and `5`*:

```
SELECT
    a.*
FROM 
    (
        SELECT aa.id, aa.name
        FROM recipes aa
        INNER JOIN ingredients_recipes bb ON aa.id = bb.recipe_id
        WHERE bb.ingredient_id IN (1,2) --Ingredients to contain
        GROUP BY aa.id, aa.name
        HAVING COUNT(*) = 2 --Count of items in containing list
    ) a
LEFT JOIN
    ingredients_recipes b ON 
        a.id = b.recipe_id AND
        b.ingredient_id IN (4,5) --Ingredients to NOT contain
WHERE 
    b.recipe_id IS NULL
```

### Explanation:

The `FROM` subselect gets all recipes that ***contain both*** ingredients `1` and `2`. If you wish to add or remove ingredients for the recipe to contain, just adjust the ingredient_ids in the `IN` list, and make sure the value in `COUNT(*)` represents the number of items in that list. What it's doing here is it's selecting recipes which contain *either* ingredients 1 or 2, which means some recipes will join on only 1 row (if it only contains one ingredient but not the other), or 2 rows (if it contains both ingredients). The `HAVING COUNT(*) = 2` then selects only the recipes which joined on **2** rows.

Once those recipes have been selected, we now have to filter out the recipes which **don't** contain ingredients `4` and `5`. We do this with a `LEFT JOIN` / `IS NULL`. Like in the `FROM` subselect, you can add or remove ingredients in the `IN` list, except that you do not have to be concerned with adjusting a `COUNT` in the `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: thanks zane, just read wildplassers reply first! thanks for your time!